# Why does this code crash using pointers in map c++ in this implementation of Trie?

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
  map<char,Node*> characters;
  bool endOfWord = false;
  Node()
  {
  }

  Node(bool endOfWordBool)
  {
    this->endOfWord = endOfWordBool;
  }
};

class Trie
{
public:
    Node* root = nullptr;
    Trie()
    {
        this->root = new Node();
    }
```

This function is the problem here.
Using next node that i set in each iteration crashes does the map stl doesn't support having pointers to object inside?

```
    void insertWord(string word)
    {
        Node* currentNode = this->root;
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            /// character is not in the map
            if(currentNode->characters.find(word[i]) != 
                   currentNode->characters.end())
            {
                cout << "before create" << endl;
                Node* nextNode = new Node();
                currentNode->characters.insert(pair<char,Node*>(word[i], 
                                               nextNode));
                currentNode = currentNode->characters.find(word[i])->second;
            }
            /// character is in the map
            else
            {
                currentNode = currentNode->characters.find(word[i])->second;
            }
        }
        currentNode->endOfWord = true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Trie* t = new Trie();
    string s = "ahmed";
    t->insertWord(s);
    return 0;
}
```

It crashes in the insertion using the set next Node. any Help? And is it a better convention to use pointers in this case or to put the object in the map?

Comment: Use a debugger to debug small programs. It's a skill worth having - will save days off your life.

Comment: *does the map stl doesn't support having pointers to object inside?* -- It does -- you have bugs in your code, it isn't an issue with `std::map`.

Comment: Add an output when a character is found as well, and then think carefully about the condition just below "character is not in the map".

Comment: and calling `currentNode->characters.find(word[i])` 3 times is not a good idea

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your code does the wrong comparison to see if the element in the map exists.

This:

```
if (currentNode->characters.find(word[i]) != currentNode->characters.end())
```

should be:

```
if (currentNode->characters.find(word[i]) == currentNode->characters.end())
```

By using the wrong comparison, you wind up using an uninitialized pointer.

---

This also demonstrates that comments can lie what the code does -- the only thing that is the truth is the code.  I'm referring to this comment right before the incorrect code:

`/// character is not in the map`

and of course the code does not determine if the character is not in the map.  It actually tests if the character *is* in the map.